# Having issues with NPM start throwing [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE] (also having weird pc issues)

Tags: html, reactjs

i created a new folder since i was having issues and maybe thought it was the directory.
so i did the following steps:

1. node - v
   result: v19.6.0
2. npx create-react-app test
   result: created the proper files.
3. cd test
   result: as expected
4. npm start
   result: [Error When i do npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u6Wv.jpg)

i now tried it on a older file that i know used to work before i did npm audit fix --force today and this is what i got: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HbKU.jpg)

note: i have had multiple issues with my computer it is a M1 macbook pro 16 inch bought brand new from apple in march 2022. i was doing my bootcamp and i kept running into path directory issues for some reason. so i factory reset. i still have some issues and i have to sudo everything.
looking for some help and some guidance thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With everything I tried uninstalling node. Didn't work
I tried

```
npm audit fix --force
```

didn't work
what worked was changing my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    }
```

I have added "--openssl-legacy-provider" flag between react-scripts and start